# Elasticsearch 5.2: Mapping Issue with date field

Tags: date, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm having a problem with properly mapping my timestamps. If I define it in *default* mapping I get a mapping parser error when importing the data.
When i did this manually for certain types it worked. 
Why is this not working as default mapping?

```
PUT database
{
  "mappings": {
       "_default_": {
         "properties": {
            "Timestamp":{
              "type":"date",
              "format":"strict_date_hour_minute_second_fraction"

    }
  }}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My own fault my Timestamp doesnt have the fraction, seems when I did it manually I used strict_date_hour_minute_second instead.